# golang no such device in syscall.Mount

Tags: go, system-calls, mount

I'm trying to use the syscall.Mount function to mount a usb pendrive and autodetect the filesystem to some folder. I fetch the device path from the kernel's netlink socket and try to mount it to `/tmp/+devicename`, in my instance `/dev/sdd1` should be mounted to `/tmp/sdd1`

I have the following lines of code in a go program

```
if err := syscall.Mount(src, target, "auto", 0, "ro"); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Mount(\"%s\", \"%s\", \"auto\", 0, \"ro\")\n",src,target)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Output:

```
main.go:47: Mount("/dev/sdd1", "/tmp/sdd1", "auto", 0, "ro")
main.go:48: no such device
```

I'm running the application with root privileges with "sudo", however it seems unable to mount using the syscall package. If i however in the terminal type `sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /tmp/sdd1` then that works fine.

What is the issue here? Is the device path somehow different when using the system call?

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: What was your workaround for this? Just call `mount` as a child process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't specify your OS but I think the problem is the same on many implementations.

On [Linux `syscall.Mount`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_linux.go?s=20289:20384#L786) just wraps `mount(2)` [which doesn't itself support the concept of an "auto" fstype](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html).

The reason the `mount(8)` **command** works with `"auto"` is because [it does its own magic](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

> If no -t option is given, or if the auto type is specified,
>   mount will try to guess the desired type.  **Mount uses the
>   blkid library for guessing the filesystem type**; if that does
>   not turn up anything that looks familiar, mount will try to
>   read the file /etc/filesystems, or, if that does not exist,
>   `/proc/filesystems`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, however i would expect the error message to be something other than "no such device".

Comment: @netbrain That's very sensible. But the man page does mention `mount(2)` returns `ENODEV` for "A filesystem not configured in the kernel".

Comment: I thought I can leave the type as "" because mount(8) works this way.. now I know more thanks to you! :) Awesome.